# Invalid HTML when adding Facebook chat suppport code using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to add the Facebook support chat module to my site using Google Tag Manager.

The code that I'm using is generated by Facebook and all I'm doing is copying it straight to Google Tag Manager, so I'm not sure why it's not working...

It keeps giving me this error:

"Invalid HTML, CSS or JavaScript found in template"

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="XXXXXXXXXXX"
  theme_color="#111111">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you added given code in a [Custom HTML](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107167?hl=en#CustomHTML) GTM Tag, in which case, plain HTML won't work (`<div class="fb-customerchat" [...]</div>`). Therefore, given code must be converted to javascript in order to work.

I'd follow the GTM documentation and make use of [User-defined (Constants) Variables](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362#constant) to store parameters or any string / value. (Optional, it will work with hardcoded values such as `var page_id = '0123456789';`)

In below example, I mixed both methods for better understanding.

```html
<script>
(function() {
    // Sample variables
    var page_id = '{{FB - PageID}}';
    var ref = '';
    var theme_color = '{{FBChat - ThemeColor}}';
    var logged_in_greeting = 'Your greeting message for logged in users'; // Can be a Custom Constant Variable Sting
    var logged_out_greeting = 'Your greeting message for logged out users'; // Can be a Custom Constant Variable Sting

    // Do not edit
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'fb-customerchat';
    el.setAttribute('page_id', page_id);
    if (ref.length) {
        el.setAttribute('ref', ref);
    }
    el.setAttribute('theme_color', theme_color);
    el.setAttribute('logged_in_greeting', logged_in_greeting);
    el.setAttribute('logged_out_greeting', logged_out_greeting);
    document.body.appendChild(el);
})();
  
  // Facebook SDK for JavaScript : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{{FB - AppID}}',
      xfbml      : true,
      // autoLogAppEvents : true,
      version    : 'v3.3'
    });
    // autoLogAppEvents replacement with logPageView
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
  
  // Customer Chat SDK : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk#install
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager uses a tool ([Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler)) that checks Javascript for validity. Unlike a browser, which will usually just ignore non-standard attributes, the linter in the Closure Compiler is pretty strict and balks at stuff it does not understand (my educated guess is that has to - CC tries to optimize Javascript to run faster, and if it does not understand what a part of your tag does it cannot optimize).

So if you get this warning, first check for bits that are not standard HTML. Like it was pointed out in the other answer, attributes like "attribution" and "page_id" and "theme_color" are good candidates. You would need to remove them one after the other to see if you can deploy your tag then, and then hope your chat will still work.