# "Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found" when injecting Builderall's Facebook Messenger bot into GTM's Custom HTML tag configuration

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I understand that GTM does not like plain HTML. It gives this response when attempting to publish the container: "Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found".

I saw part of my needed answer from a similar question: [Invalid HTML when adding Facebook chat suppport code using Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803050/invalid-html-when-adding-facebook-chat-suppport-code-using-google-tag-manager).

However, I don't know much anything regarding coding and just getting into it. Any help with injecting this 3rd party script into GTM would be greatly appreciated.

There are about 50,000 other people using this 3rd party software Builderall, and so if you can help me, you'll be helping them too, I'm sure.

```
<script id="builderall_ws_bot" src="https://chatbot.eb4us.com/bot.js" bot_id="7762" usr="22365"></script>
```

Comment: That is really hard to answer within the rules of this site, because it is really a duplicate of what you have linked to. The linter (the thing that checks the syntax) complains about non-standard attributes such as bot_id and usr, and to make it work you would have to generate the script tag with attributes programmatically via a javascript function. That is the same function as in the answer over there, only instead of document.createElement('div'); you do document.createElement('script');.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, though I may not be able to implement it myself at this time. Thank you for the explanation.